# Fixed position menu bar goes behind JS slideshow when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a simple static site. I use SlideJS free Javascript image slider on the page.
I have a fixed position menu bar on the page and when I scroll down and through the slider it disappears behind it.

[Here comes the menu](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140120/K_perny_felv_tel__1__www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

[And hiding here](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140120/K_perny_felv_tel__2__www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

How can I make it to stay on the top?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: At least if you were linking to your site .... seems like `z-index` issue

Comment: Also please include the images in the question rather than linking to them (click the toolbar icon near the middle that looks like a postcard).

Comment: I can't inlcude the images without 10 or more reputation. When I posted my question i only had 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well by using my psychic powers i'm sensing that your whole menu needs a z-index larger than the js slider.

Try something like this:

```
.menu-wrapper-on-the-top{
    z-index:99999;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought z-index but I didn't use a number what is big enough. Yours is big enough!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a z-index value to your fixed menu in CSS.

Ha bármi kérdésed van, szólj! :)

Comment: Köszi! Igen végülis azzal meg tudtam oldani :)